# How to install python modules and dependents easily?

Tags: python

Are there any easy installation tools like "perl -MCPAN -e shell;" to install python modules and its dependents???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[pip](http://pip.openplans.org/) is the most up to date tool to do this: you use it by issuing the command 
`pip install <packagename>`

The "old" way of doing the same is to easy_install:

```
easy_install <packagename>
```

If you have `easy_install` already on your system, it is advisable to run `easy_install pip` to upgrade to **pip**

Both of these install packages from the [Python Package Index (pypi)](http://pypi.python.org/pypi)
The package that provides the `easy_install` command is usually called *python-setuptools* (or something similar)