# Error accessing mercurial with non-root user

Tags: linux, bash, mercurial

I am trying to give a non-root user the ability to run mercurial commands from the shell. When I log in as the user and type "hg", I get this message:

```
abort: couldn't find mercurial libraries in [/usr/local/bin /usr/lib/python24.zip /usr/lib/python2.4 /usr/lib/python2.4/plat-linux2 /usr/lib/python2.4/lib-tk /usr/lib/python2.4/lib-dynload /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Numeric /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/gtk-2.0]
(check your install and PYTHONPATH)
```

I do not have this problem as the root. I can run mercurial commands from any directory.

My problem is that I'm not very familiar with Linux at all, and so I don't know exactly how I'm supposed to change my PYTHONPATH variable (if indeed that's what I'm trying to do). I don't even know where the PYTHONPATH variable is being stored to see what's written there now.

Can someone tell me where the PYTHONPATH (or even regular PATH) environment variable is stored in Linux, and what steps I might take to remove the error method I'm getting above? If it helps, I'm using Putty and SSH to access the server.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Which Linux?  Did you install Mercurial as a package or by hand?

Comment: CentOS, and I installed by hand.

Comment: FWIW, I followed these instructions here: http://w-i-l-t.tumblr.com/post/165104796/mercurial-install-centos-5-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PYTHONPATH` is just an [environment variable](http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles/030.html) that gets *prepended* to the python's internal search path. To see what is in there, do the following in python shell:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

It should print something like:

```
['', '/usr/lib64/python27.zip', '/usr/lib64/python2.7', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/webkit-1.0', '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info']
```

In practice, I would guess your shell is **bash** so the places where the environment variables can be set are:
`/etc/profile`, `/etc/bashrc`, `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc` - the first 2 being system wide and the latter per user.

For further explanation, see [this blog article abour bashrc and profile](http://stefaanlippens.net/bashrc_and_others)

**EDIT**
To fix this, the probably the easiest way is to install Mercurial via pip (I am assuming that you do not have Mercurial in the official repository for your Linux distribution, but usually `python-setuptools` or similar, that provides `easy_install` is). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415166/how-to-install-python-modules-and-dependents-easily/) for instructions.

Comment: Thanks for the help. In responding to the comment from Mike and looking at what you wrote, I realized that I just needed to make the same entry in my ~/.bash_profile file that I had done during installation when logged in as the root.  I actually didn't know that the ~ directory was user-specific...doh!

Comment: On CentOS - I always install the EPEL repository and install mercurial via "yum" from there. See http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-fedora-centos-linux-enable-epel-repo/